# REGEX_EXTRACT for discrete values

Tags: apache-pig

I don't understand the regex_extract function. It worked fine for simple regex but I don't understand the returned value for something like :

```
REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'([Monday|Tuesday|Saturday]).*',1) as day;
```

I tried also with '(["Monday...' but it finds each character M / o / n /d / a / y. Is it possible to use the REGEX_EXTRACT function with some discrete values (e.g. the weekday names)?

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `[]`. These indicate that you want to use character classes, which does not make sense here.

Comment: thanks. It works OK.  How to add the 'ignore case' flag to the above regex? I tried '?i(monday|tuesday|saturday).* ' , 1) and it raised an error:  org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2078: Caught error from UDF: org.apache.pig.builtin.REGEX_EXTRACT [RegexExtract : Mal-Formed Regular expression

Comment: ?i should be enclosed  by function bracket, change like this it will work. '(?i)([Monday|Tuesday|Saturday]).*'

Comment: Alternatively, try `LOWER($0...`